# Defining market demand for an item based on previous sales data

Tags: php, probability

I'm working an application that has a module that needs to define how likely an item will sell if listed on Amazon based on a set of previous sales rank data.  If you're not familiar with the Amazon sales rank, it is essentially a number defined to all items on Amazon that ranks previous sales that item is currently seeing in relation to all other items in that category.  It's a proprietary number but it essentially means sales rank #1 is currently selling the most possible copies on Amazon.com while a sales rank of 1,000,000 means that there are 999,999 other items selling more copies.

I've got a dataset that includes months of previous salesranks; one per day like this:

```
$previousranks = array(
    array('1/4/2010',567),
    array('1/5/2010',674),
    array('1/6/2010',505),
    array('1/6/2010',343),
    array('1/6/2010',578),
    array('1/6/2010',789),
    array('1/6/2010',1012),
);
```

I've also got the current sales rank to compare with.  What I'm wanting to know if this item is in the "low dip" of a demand graph.  I refer to the "low dip" by if you plot these ranks on a X-Y axis with the dates as the X axis and the salesranks as the Y axis.  I need to this function to decide if it's among the low sales ranks for it's past history if that makes any sense.

EDIT: From the array above, I'd need to know if the current sales rank is between the 505 and the 578, for example.  That would be the "low dip".  What I don't quite understand is how to define the "low dip" because the range will not be the same all the time.

Comment: I don' get, WHEN an item is in the "low dip".

Comment: The items I'm attempting to get a good feel for market demand are textbooks.  Textbook demand is cyclical as it goes up and down in demand with school semesters.  A low dip can be defined as if a sales rank the textbooks currently has is at the same or lower than what it had dipped previously.

Comment: Do you know how the rank is computed? I assume it's for items of "similar nature", is it a rank over a moving period? Asking because rank based just on a day's data may be volatile, but rank over a sliding window would then pick up changes with a delay effect.

Comment: The rank is proprietary to Amazon.  For example, there are around 10,000,000 books offered in Amazon's catalog.  If a book has a rank of 1, this means it's currently selling the most copies of all the other books.  You are correct about a rank based on the day's data being volatile.  This is exactly the reason why I'm looking for a better way to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, I understood your question. You want to determine, if the item ever had a higher sales rank (= lower sales amount) than the current?

You could sort the array by descending sales ranks. Then compare the first array entry (which has the highest sales rank) to your current sales rank.

To sort a multidimensional array (in this case, descending by the past sales ranks), use [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), where you can define your own comparison function:

```
function mySort($a, $b) 
{
    return $b[1] - $a[1];
}

usort($previousranks, 'mySort');
if($currentrank > $previousranks[0][1])
    // current sales rank highest, do something
```

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm looking for.  However, I also don't think I've probably given a good indication of what I need.  I've updated the question.